# Freeswitch: mod_xml_curl and call groups

Tags: freeswitch

I am currently switching from static configs to using `mod_xml_curl` and have encountered a problem with setting up call groups.

Inside my dialplan (served dynamically, working as expected) I am bridging to a group:

`<action application="bridge" data="${group_call(call-group@domain-a.com)}"/>`

Freeswitch is making a request with `section=directory&action=group_call` to the web server, to which I respond with a chunk of the directory containing the group and all relevant users:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
    <section name="directory">
        <domain name="domain-a.com">
            <params>
                <param name="dial-string" value="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}" />
            </params>
            <variables>
                <variable name="user_context" value="domain-a.com" />
            </variables>
            <group name="call-group">
                <users>
                    <user id="john" number-alias="1000">
                        <params>
                            <param name="password" value="1234" />
                            <param name="vm-password" value="1000" />
                        </params>
                        <variables>
                            <variable name="toll_allow" value="domestic,international,local" />
                            <variable name="accountcode" value="1000" />
                            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_name" value="John at domain-a.com" />
                            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="1234567" />
                        </variables>
                    </user>
                    <user id="lucy" number-alias="1001">
                        <params>
                            <param name="password" value="1234" />
                            <param name="vm-password" value="1000" />
                        </params>
                        <variables>
                            <variable name="toll_allow" value="domestic,international,local" />
                            <variable name="accountcode" value="1001" />
                            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_name" value="Lucy" />
                            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="12345678" />
                        </variables>
                    </user>
                </users>
            </group>
        </domain>
    </section>
</document>
```

However, `group_call()` seems to fail and in the logs I get ``:

```
2016-02-24 10:42:14.249534 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1498 SET sofia/internal/michael@domain-a.com [call_timeout]=[15]
2016-02-24 10:42:14.529107 [CONSOLE] mod_xml_curl.c:323 XML response is in /tmp/2f772a8a-4c3a-46f2-834f-b9ba2c735feb.tmp.xml
EXECUTE sofia/internal/michael@domain-a.com bridge(error/NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION)
```

Perhaps anyone has experience setting up group calls with `mod_xml_curl` and could explain what exactly Freeswitch is expecting in the response?

Answer (score 3):

After a little gnashing of teeth, I got this working.  The clue was [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_commands) underneath the group_call description:

> Please note: If you need to have outgoing user variables set in leg B,
> **make sure you don't have dial-string and group-dial-string in your
> domain or dialed group variables list; instead set dial-string or
> group-dial-string in the default group of the user**. This way
> group_call will return user/101 and user/ would set all your user
> variables to the leg B channel.

So, when you receive an action of type `group_call`, move the `dial-string` param to the group level, so instead of

```
<domain name="domain-a.com">
    <params>
        <param name="dial-string" value="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}" />
    </params>
    <variables>
        <variable name="user_context" value="domain-a.com" />
    </variables>
    <group name="call-group">
        <users>
            <user id="john" number-alias="1000">
    ...
```

send this

```
<domain name="domain-a.com">
    <variables>
        <variable name="user_context" value="domain-a.com" />
    </variables>
    <group name="call-group">
        <params>
            <param name="dial-string" value="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}" />
        </params>
        <users>
            <user id="john" number-alias="1000">
    ...
```

After I made that change, everything was hunky dory.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your dialplan.It's not generated perfectly. just check the domain-a.com context in the dialplan.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, however there seems to be no problem with the dialplan:
I have disabled `xml_curl` and tested things with static configs, everythings is working correctly.
Then I enabled the `directory` binding, keeping the dialplan static, and I get the same error with group calls.

Comment: K i will do one thing i will check same on my system.let you know how to handle this situation

Comment: are you able to solve this problem or still persist?

Comment: I still haven't solved it, but I was thinking about ditching the group_call function and trying to imitate it by manually generating a bridge string on the webserver when dialplan is being queried. Haven't had a chance to try it though.

Comment: Tried the above method, generating a dialplan extension on the web-server (something like `<action application="bridge" data="user/john|user/lucy" />`), seems to do the job. Although still not clear, what was wrong with `group_call`

Comment: yeh this will work even group call will work.i think you have did mistake in somewhere group call.